# Why does increasing padding in this <a> increase the vertical margin?

Tags: google-chrome, padding, css

This is probably the most unusual CSS behavior I have ever seen:

I have an extremely simple table that consists of two cells - one with plain text and another with a link:

```
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Hello, world!
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">Hello, world!</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have also applied the following CSS to the table:

```
div.content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}

table td {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

table td a {
  background-color: orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When rendered in Chrome 28, I see the following:

[image]

Why is there a large amount of red above and below the link? I have specified `height: 100%;` for the link, so it should be taking up the full height of the `<td>`, which has an explicit height.

Comment: This is a known bug, unfortunately. There's a whole set of bug reports surrounding box-sizing and tables in chrome. I guess you just need to jury-rig something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely an issue with the box-sizing:border-box attribute. My guess is that putting that inside a table cell (which is treated differently then a div) is confusing the browser. Often, new techniques + old techniques don't mix.

I would suggest doing the following:

```
table td a {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

The width:100% was unneeded since the table cell already expanded to the text width + padding width. For some reason, it doesn't seem to add the padding to the height 100% with the table cell (go figure, weirdness with tables! lol). If you need it to expand to a larger table cell width, I would suggest then putting the width:100% back but then ditch the horizontal padding (i.e. put padding:8px 0px;).

Comment: Also if you want to get your text perfectly aligned vertically, try putting: padding:0px; line-height:50px; (the line height is a trick to align text vertically, but it must match the cell height and can only be on ONE line)

Comment: In this particular case, the cell will always display a single line, so this could work.

Comment: And this is why Mozilla chooses to err on the side of caution and [keep `-moz-box-sizing` prefixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=243412)...

Comment: Yea, well box-sizing is a relatively new thing. Especially compared to tables. ;) Anyways if this works just use this then-- background-color: orange; box-sizing: border-box; display: block; height: 100%; padding: 0 8px; width: 100%; line-height: 50px;

Comment: Not for IE, that's for sure :P

Comment: IE + box-sizing = fail (except maybe IE10)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think its the box-sizing attribute causing this, change your css to:

```
table td a {
   background-color: black;
   height: 100%;
   display:block;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 12px;
 }
```

Hope that helps;

Comment: Then the horizontal padding would cause the width of the `<a>` to spill outside the parent `<td>`.

Comment: That's where I've changed the padding CSS as well. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I need the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting height in `px` for `a` as

```
table td a {
  background-color: orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That only removes a tiny sliver (maybe `1px` or so) of red.

Comment: You can set the `height` for `<a>` in `px` instead of `%` (which won't affect sometimes). You have set the `td` `height` as `50px`. set the same to `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Add This Code to table td:

```
display:inline-block;
```

because There is some difference between tables and divisions in box modeling.

you must set display-block on any none-block element for apply box-model style.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of a jury-rig: http://jsfiddle.net/rTAwd/

We're using a line height to adjust the cell's height, so we don't need to mess with vertical alignment, and relying on a wrapper div to provide our background and padding.

```
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello, world!</td>
            <td>
                <div> <a href="#">Hello, world!</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css

```
div.content {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}
table td {
    background-color: red;
}
table td div a {
    line-height: 2em;
}
table td div {
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug, i had the same issue a while ago, if you want the text to vertically align in the middle, instead of using `display:block` on the `<a>` tag use `display:table` and use `border-spacing` instead of `padding`, like this:

```
table td a {
  background-color: orange;  
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  border-spacing: 8px 13px;
}
```

I removed the width:100% too since it will do it by default, you can see an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ML3mV/).
 `border-spacing` is the CSS property for `cellpadding`.